# Where do Staff in a Castle Stay/Live?

Tags: medieval

In a castle, where do staff members, particularly guards, live? Do they live in the palace, on the palace grounds, or do they commute to work like the rest of us?

Comment: What time period are you looking at, early/mid medieval, late medieval, or later?

Comment: Up to the 1940s or so slaves / servants / domestic help almost always lived in the appartment / house / manor / palace they were working in. (At least in European context; I have no idea how they arranged things in China or Japan.) A servant or armsman who is not there when one needs them is not of much use.

Comment: why the magic tag?

Comment: Note that castles and palaces are very different things.  To get an idea of what a real castle was like, try looking up the floor plan.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort whatsoever. Simply googling the specified question and/or reading up on castles on e.g. Wikipedia would provide you with all the information you need and more.

Comment: I'm removing the \[magic\] tag because this question does not involve any magic or magical elements whatsoever.

Comment: It may also very well run afoul of the exclusion of historical facts in Worldbuilding's scope: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "\[not about\] Historical events of or historical facts about the real world, except when provided as examples or comparisons in the construction of an imaginary world"

Comment: @dot_Sp0T "Shows no research effort" is not a reason to vote to close; it is a reason to downvote. (Actually, it's one of the three *canonical* reasons to vote down a question.) Please use the appropriate tool. Close votes are not super-downvotes.

Comment: What type of castle/palace is it? is it strictly military, nobility or a mix of both?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling sorry my bad. But I can't retract the vote anymore now

Answer (score 3):

What you write makes me uncertain if you see the difference between a *castle* and a *palace*. A castle might contain a [palas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palas), which was no palace.

- A palace is a large and comfortable building for the nobility, possibly including administrative offices.
- A castle is a defensive building where nobility might live in peacetime as well. The key thing is the strength of the castle walls, the comfort of the quarters is secondary.

A castle would be built to hold a sufficient population and their supplies during a siege. This might include peasants and lifestock from the surrounding area. So in peacetime there is enough space to hold a caretaker staff.

Within the castle there might be different buildings. A donjon or [keep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep) which served as last retreat in battle and living quarters for the nobility, who might also live in the palas if the castle had one.

Servants would live in small rooms within these buildings, or in shacks on the castle grounds.

Comment: Yes, castles looking like palaces is the Disney version of reality.

Comment: Please don't answer obviously off-topic questions - it sets a bad example especially because you're such a high rep user.

Comment: @RonJohn, it's not so much Disney as Ludwig II of Bavaria on whose marvellous edifices the Disney castles are based, but they were largely built after the heyday of castle warfare.

Answer (score 0):

A castle on an island will often have a seaside town and some people from that town may work in the castle, likewise castles may have towns built around them especially if they're on a major river or trade route. When there's a siege everyone who isn't important or strictly necessary tends to get kicked out of the castle because the fewer people there are in the castle the longer their supplies will last. In the afore mentioned seaside town the inhabitants (including much of the castle's staff) will evacuate on fishing boats or whatever's available. Castles surrounded by larger towns or cities tend not to get besieged as the town/city itself is going to put up a fight and besieging a castle on a major trade route means you're going to make enemies of every vested interest in the region.

Really there's no strict rules about who lives where, it's a combination of practicality and culture, consider where you would want your guards/servants to live given the circumstances and that's pretty much what they guy in charge would think too.

Comment: I am not sure that you understood the purpose of castles built in towns. They are there to protect the populace, not to 'kick them out'..